# Write() works even if i blocked my file by other process

Tags: c, flock

When I run my program:

```
int i = fork();

if (!i){
    int id = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);
    if(flock(id, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == -1)
        perror("flock_ch");
if(write(id, "child", 5)) printf("child did it\n");
else perror("write_ch");
sleep(3);
    close(id);
}
else {
    int id = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);
    if(flock(id, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == -1)
       perror("flock_PR");
if(write(id, "parent", 6)) printf("parent did it\n");
else perror("write_pr");
sleep(3);
    close(id);
}

wait(NULL);
```

I expect that only one process will write something in the file, but even if the file is locked, two of processes write in the file.

Comment: You are doing `flock` with `LOCK_NB`, so the call may return _without_ holding the lock. Remove the `LOCK_NB`. Then, one of the processes will get it first and they will be serialized. But, if you want to ensure the file gets _both_ outputs intact (e.g. `childparent` or `parentchild`), after the `flock` calls, you should do: `lseek(id,0,2);` to move to end of file before writing. For this, using `O_APPEND` instead of `O_WRONLY` may be useful. If you did that, you wouldn't need to use the `flock` or `lseek` calls in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both processes are writing to the file because you're ignoring the error return value from `flock()`. When I run your code, I see:

```
parent did it
flock_ch: Resource temporarily unavailable
child did it
```

That `flock_ch: Resource temporarily unavailable` is because `flock()` is returning with an error and telling you the file is locked. You're printing out an error message, but not otherwise responding to the error message. You probably want to either (a) exit or (b) loop until `flock()` succeeds.

Using a loop might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LOCK_FLAGS (LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)

void parent() {
  int fd = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);

  while (flock(fd, LOCK_FLAGS) == -1) {
    printf("parent waiting for lock\n");
    sleep(1);
  }
  printf("parent acquired lock\n");

  if (write(fd, "parent", 6) >= 0) {
    printf("parent wrote to file\n");
  } else {
    perror("parent: write failed:");
    exit(1);
  }

  sleep(3);

  close(fd);
}

void child() {
  int fd = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);

  while (flock(fd, LOCK_FLAGS) == -1) {
    printf("child waiting for lock\n");
    sleep(1);
  }
  printf("child acquired lock\n");

  if (write(fd, "child", 6) >= 0) {
    printf("child wrote to file\n");
  } else {
    perror("child: write failed:");
    exit(1);
  }

  sleep(3);

  close(fd);
}

int main() {
  // ensure "shared.txt" exists
  int fd = open("shared.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
  close(fd);

  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {
    child();
    exit(0);
  }
  parent();
  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Running the above produces:

```
parent acquired lock
parent wrote to file
child waiting for lock
child waiting for lock
child waiting for lock
child acquired lock
child wrote to file
```

Alternately, drop the `LOCK_NB` flag so that `flock()` blocks until the lock is available. That might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LOCK_FLAGS (LOCK_EX) // | LOCK_NB)

void parent() {
  int fd = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);

  if (flock(fd, LOCK_FLAGS) == -1) {
      perror("parent: flock:");
      exit(1);
  }

  printf("parent acquired lock\n");

  if (write(fd, "parent", 6) >= 0) {
    printf("parent wrote to file\n");
  } else {
    perror("parent: write failed:");
    exit(1);
  }

  sleep(3);

  close(fd);
}

void child() {
  int fd = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);

  if (flock(fd, LOCK_FLAGS) == -1) {
      perror("child: flock:");
      exit(1);
  }

  printf("child acquired lock\n");

  if (write(fd, "child", 6) >= 0) {
    printf("child wrote to file\n");
  } else {
    perror("child: write failed:");
    exit(1);
  }

  sleep(3);

  close(fd);
}

int main() {
  // ensure "shared.txt" exists
  int fd = open("shared.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
  close(fd);

  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {
    child();
    exit(0);
  }
  parent();
  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

And running the above produces:

```
parent acquired lock
parent wrote to file
child acquired lock
child wrote to file
```